# Spring @autowired annotation example

Tags: spring

Can someone explain spring @autowired example which is given in the below tutorials point link?

Whatever id I give in the place of bean id which is "spellChecker" it takes that and injects it. for example instead of bean id="spellChecker" if I give bean id="a" in Beans.xml

[Spring auto-wired annotation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_autowired_annotation.htm)

Comment: The `@Autowired` annotation is Spring's annotation for depencency injection. Read the [Spring documentation](https://spring.io/docs), or a book, or follow a course if you want to learn what dependency injection is - this topic is too broad to explain here. Is there something specific you do not understand about the blog post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some point for autowire functionality and how it is works interally,

1) If  your application has two bean for same class then it would not works.for that you have to give same bean name as you given in bean.xml file.
  like one bean is -> id = "spellChecker1"
       second bean is -> id = "spellChecker2"
   now you have to autowired like 
         bean 1 -> @autowired 
                   private SpellChecker spellChecker1;
         bean 2 -> @autowired 
                   private SpellChecker spellChecker2;
2) if your application has only one bean for class then it would automatically detect bean and inject.
 In your case application has only one bean **id="a"** so spring automatically detect that bean for class **SpellChecker**.